# Julia: Parallel For loop with large data move

Tags: for-loop, dictionary, parallel-processing, julia

I want to run a parallel for loop. I need each of my processes to have access to 2 large dictionaries, `gene_dict` and `transcript_dict`. This is what I tried first

```
@everywhere( function EM ... end )

generefs  = [ @spawnat i genes for i in 2:nprocs()]
dict1refs = [ @spawnat i gene_dict for i in 2:nprocs()]
dict2refs = [ @spawnat i transcript_dict for i in 2:nprocs()]

result = @parallel (vcat) for i in 1:length(genes)
  EM(genes[i], gene_dict, transcript_dict)
end
```

but I get the following error on all processes (not just on 5):

```
exception on 5: ERROR: genes not defined
 in anonymous at no file:1514
 in anonymous at multi.jl:1364
 in anonymous at multi.jl:820
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:593
 in run_work_thunk at multi.jl:602
 in anonymous at task.jl:6
UndefVarError(:genes)
```

I thought `@spawnat` would move the three data structures I need to all of the processes. My first thought is maybe this move takes awhile and the parallel for loop tries to run before the data transfer is complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The data is moved by `@spawnat` but it is not bound to variables with the same name as the name on the master node. Instead the data is saved in the fairly hidden `Dict` named `Base.PGRP` on the workers. To access the values, you'll have to `fetch` the `RemoteRef`s which in your case would be something like

`result = @parallel (vcat) for i in 1:length(genes)
  EM(fetch(genes[i]), fetch(gene_dict[i]), fetch(transcript_dict[i]))
end`

Comment: Your solution worked great when I was working in an interactive julia session. But when I tried to call my julia script from console I still get the error I mentioned. Do you have any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: I don't see why it should make a difference. What happens if you run the script with `include("stript.jl")` from an interactive julia session?

Comment: Are you able to make a small reproducible example of this?

Comment: I've posted it in julia issues on github with some dropbox shared code: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/9476

Comment: *WARNING* vcat is a terribly slow.  use something like sharedarray instead.